# Why is it everytime I try to get a user to input an integer in Swift, Xcode makes me put a "!" after the variable

Tags: swift, input, readline

I'm working on a code where I need to get 2 user inputted integers and output the smaller one. I am new to swift, and every time I try to get a user to input an integer, I get this error "Value of optional type 'String?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'String'". I don't understand why I always need to put a "!" after readLine(), but thats what it makes me do.

```
print("Enter the first integer")
let int1 = Int(readLine()!)
print("Enter the second integer")
let int2 = Int(readLine()!)
let small_int = min(int1!, int2!) 
print("The smaller integer is", small_int)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1641199-readline):

> The string of characters read from standard input. If EOF has already been reached when readLine() is called, the result is nil.

... so, simplified, `readLine(strippingNewline:)` always doesn't have to return value and it also can return `nil` (no value), so return type is `String?` which is optional type which says that your constant is `String` or `nil`

If you need to get non-optional value you can either force-unwrap optional value or check if value exists and if does, assign some non-optional constant/variable using optional binding. The same you can do for `Int` initializer which can also return `nil` since not every `String` is necessarily a integer

```
print("Enter the first integer")
let input1 = readLine()
print("Enter the second integer")
let input2 = readLine()

if let string1 = input1, let int1 = Int(string1), let string2 = input2, let int2 = Int(string2) {
    let small_int = min(int1, int2)
    print("The smaller integer is", small_int)
} else {
    print("Invalid input")
}
```

alternatively you can use default value so if value is `nil` your constant will be assigned with given default value

```
print("Enter the first integer")
let int1 = Int(readLine() ?? "") ?? 0
print("Enter the second integer")
let int2 = Int(readLine() ?? "") ?? 0
let small_int = min(int1, int2) 
print("The smaller integer is", small_int)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend writing your code in a defensive way. That includes dealing with unexpected results.

Both, `readline()` and `Int()` can return `nil`. As the other answer already explained, readline returns nil if you have reached EOF.

So my recommendation is to use the `??` operator to provide alternative values for the failure cases. For example: `let line = readline() ?? “”`.

Alternatively, especially inside methods, you may want to bail out early with `guard` and have the actual work at the end of the method with validated and non-nil inputs.

With that in mind, your example can be rewritten like this:

```swift
let line = readline() ?? “”
let int1 = Int(line) ?? 0
//...
```

Or as a method with guard:

```swift
func smallerInteger() -> Int? {
   print("Enter the first integer")
   guard let line1 = readline() else {
      return nil
   }
   guard let int1 = Int(line1) else {
      return nil
   }
   print("Enter the second integer")
   guard let line2 = readline() else {
      return nil
   }
   guard let int2 = Int(line2) else {
      return nil
   }
   return min(int1, int2)
}
```

Of course this can be improved by returning both an Int? and an Error? like `(Int?, Error?)` or with the latest Swift, a `Result`.